# Xcode UI Testing: Executing a Test Conditionally

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Using Xcode UI Testing, I want to implement code that runs if a particular UI element in present in the app. My app has a logged-in state and I want to log the user out if they are currently logged in. I've been unable to find documentation to suggest a way out of this paper bag.

Everything I've read shows two possible paths: using `XCTAssert` (which would cause my test to fail immediately if the element weren't present) and using `XCTExpectation` (which would cause my test to time out if the element weren't present). I need a more simple way to run different code if the app is in a given state.

To put it in code, I'm looking for something like this:

```
if let signOutElement = app.collectionViews.staticTexts["Sign Out"] {
    signOutElement.tap()
}
```

Alas, this doesn't work.

Comment: In my experience testing is usually done with a fairly rigid state of mind - you put the app in the state you want so you can test specific parts of the code.  So in this case, you should KNOW that the user is in a logged in state and thus needs to be logged out.

You could theoretically achieve this with some sort of timer on the page that fires every so often and looks for a Sign Out, but again not something that you'd necessarily do through test imo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a conditional during testing. The problem with your code is that it is nonsense from a Swift point of view; `if let` is meaningless here, as your expression does not return an Optional. You do still have to talk legal Swift, after all.

Why not try something like this?

```
if app.collectionViews.staticTexts["Sign Out"].exists
```

Comment: I also realized there's an exists method on XCUIElement. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yikes, if you feel that strongly about it!

Comment: Thank you for fixing that! Yes, I do feel strongly because I don't want bad code appearing over my name. You are the one fighting on the front lines and wrestling this code to the ground, so you know best what works. I appreciate your help.